# While doing inference in GUI, how can I suppress the labels and confidence score from Yolov5 model?

Tags: python, user-interface, yolo, yolov5

I need to remove the labels and confidence score from the YOLOv5 model.
I have already removed (hide) the labels and confidence score in the detect.py file but I am doing skin integration so I am using best.pt weight file directly and I am not able to hide the labels and confidence score.
Is there any solution available?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import torch

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')

# Image
img = 'https://ultralytics.com/images/zidane.jpg'

# Inference
results = model(img)